# SVG looks strange on mobile browsers

Tags: android, svg, mobile-safari, mobile-browser

Here's a PNG version of my logo image:

[image: PNG logo]

Here's a screenshot of an SVG version of my logo as seen on a PC:

[image: SVG logo - PC screenshot]

Here's a screenshot of how that same SVG logo looks on an iPhone and an android phone:

[image: SVG logo on mobile browsers]

What's going on? Why does the mobile version look so blurred and the gradient not work on the pink petal?

Here's the actual SVG code. (For some reason, the font doesn't load in the snippet code but it loads just fine from my website: http://www.cafenocturne.com/testpage/images/svg/CafeLogoFontSVG.svg

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="http://www.cafenocturne.com/fonts/FontPorcelain.css" ?>
  <svg width="300px" height="300px" viewBox="-50 0 447 466" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" style="overflow: visible" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g id="logo">
      <g id="petal">
        <defs>
          <radialGradient id="gradpetal" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" cx="8rem" cy="14.5rem">
            <stop stop-color="#ffdcfd" offset=".01" />
            <stop stop-color="#ff94dd" offset="0.15" />
            <stop stop-color="#ff92dd" offset="0.17" />
            <stop stop-color="#feadef" offset=".32" />
            <stop stop-color="#fec3ff" offset=".49" />
            <stop stop-color="#fec3ff" offset=".55" />
            <stop stop-color="#ff94dd" offset=".85" />
            <stop stop-color="#ff94dd" offset="1" />
          </radialGradient>
        </defs>

        <path id="svgpetal" fill="url(#gradpetal)" stroke="url(#gradpetal)" stroke-width="2px" filter="url(#dropshadow)" d=" M 238.54 53.89 C 246.99 52.67 255.63 52.63 264.04 54.18 C 266.61 54.66 269.01 56.33 269.99 58.80 C 273.60 68.31 270.50 78.82 273.54 88.44 C 274.39 91.28 276.62 93.61 279.36 94.71 C 288.28 98.60 298.56 96.58 307.45 100.58 C 310.41 101.97 312.32 105.01 312.36 108.28 C 314.10 131.28 305.41 153.92 292.57 172.66 C 283.39 185.84 272.24 197.87 258.68 206.66 C 236.86 220.77 210.61 226.11 184.96 227.17 C 174.33 227.35 163.68 228.06 153.07 227.17 C 146.99 226.56 140.17 224.70 136.60 219.33 C 131.70 210.74 131.82 200.46 132.27 190.89 C 133.16 171.85 134.93 152.54 141.46 134.50 C 147.98 115.64 159.29 98.46 174.28 85.27 C 192.18 69.14 214.50 57.22 238.54 53.89 Z"
        />

        <defs>
          <radialGradient id="gradspine" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" cx="8rem" cy="14.5rem">
            <stop stop-color="#fe9bee" offset=".15" />
            <stop stop-color="#fec3ff" offset=".20" />
            <stop stop-color="#fec3ff" offset=".32" />
            <stop stop-color="#feadef" offset=".39" />
            <stop stop-color="#ff92dd" offset="0.45" />
            <stop stop-color="#ff94dd" offset="0.5" />
            <stop stop-color="#ffdcfd" offset="1" />
          </radialGradient>
        </defs>

        <path id="svgspine" fill="url(#gradspine)" d=" M 273.33 92.20 C 273.84 92.35 274.88 92.65 275.39 92.80 C 271.04 106.15 262.39 117.73 252.21 127.23 C 245.23 134.25 238.16 141.26 230.01 146.95 C 220.43 154.24 209.84 159.99 199.02 165.20 C 191.88 168.52 186.16 174.09 180.76 179.69 C 173.54 187.94 168.46 197.87 160.80 205.75 C 154.38 212.01 146.82 216.96 139.02 221.31 C 137.69 220.37 137.65 219.57 138.90 218.94 C 143.54 216.35 148.01 213.49 152.21 210.23 C 163.70 202.21 170.01 189.31 178.67 178.68 C 184.55 172.81 190.49 166.69 198.11 163.10 C 213.73 155.96 228.45 146.73 241.11 135.10 C 245.70 130.69 250.19 126.18 254.78 121.78 C 262.78 113.26 269.72 103.41 273.33 92.20 Z"
        />
      </g>

      <path id="svgmoon" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" filter="url(#dropshadow)" d=" M 125.71 4.83 C 132.21 2.77 139.01 1.97 145.66 0.59 C 133.00 9.73 120.78 19.62 110.14 31.11 C 95.76 46.55 84.01 64.51 76.14 84.11 C 58.65 127.32 60.32 176.94 76.88 220.16 C 82.95 234.74 89.81 249.48 101.01 260.89 C 110.02 269.31 119.13 277.77 129.66 284.30 C 148.41 296.68 169.88 304.84 192.02 308.51 C 216.22 312.44 241.09 311.13 265.04 306.14 C 286.12 301.57 306.41 293.94 325.81 284.60 C 332.75 280.95 339.69 277.31 346.63 273.65 C 338.54 285.17 330.90 297.05 321.77 307.80 C 309.52 322.73 294.55 335.51 277.40 344.48 C 247.85 359.93 213.98 364.68 181.02 365.43 C 146.84 365.46 112.77 355.39 83.93 337.08 C 54.54 318.15 30.44 290.79 16.33 258.74 C 7.91 239.92 2.64 219.67 0.89 199.12 C 0.42 190.44 0.54 181.74 0.82 173.06 C 3.04 133.90 17.63 95.66 41.68 64.69 C 63.28 37.42 92.09 14.92 125.71 4.83 Z"
      />

      <g id="text">
        <text style="font-family: PorcelainRegular; 
    font-size: 65px;
    stroke: #000000;
    fill: #ffffff;
    overflow: visible;
    filter: url(#dropshadow);">
          <tspan x="0" y="0">`</tspan>
          <tspan x="70" y="120">Cafe</tspan>
          <tspan x="-30" y="290">Nocturne</tspan>
        </text>
      </g>
      <defs>
        <filter id="dropshadow" width="250px" height="250px">
          <feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceAlpha" dx="3" dy="3" />
          <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" in="offOut" stdDeviation="3" />
          <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut" mode="normal" />
        </filter>
      </defs>

    </g>
  </svg>
```